# 2010 VB.Net MAster Detail form not saving record

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I am new to VB.net and have created a simple master detail windows form.  I created a two table data set and then dropped the master table on the form as a continues form or a detail form with several text boxes to hold the data. The child form is a data grid.

test data that I have added directly to the database shows up with the proper parent child relationships on the form.  I can also enter new records into the database using the parent only portion of my form.

When I attempt to enter a complete record with data in both the parent form and the child data grid I get this error.

> The `INSERT` statement conflicted with the `FOREIGN KEY` constraint
>   `FK_tblComplainant_tblUseOfForce`. The conflict occurred in database
>   `"C:\SQLFILES\CCTS_2.MDF"`, table `"dbo.tblUseOfForce"`, column `'UOFID'`.
>   The statement has been terminated.

`tblComplainant` is the child and `tblUseOfForce` is the master.  The code used to save this record is as follows:

```
 Private Sub TblUseOfForceBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) HandlesTblUseOfForceBindingNavigatorSaveItem.Click
    Me.Validate()
    Me.TblUseOfForceBindingSource.EndEdit()
    Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.UseOfForceDataSet)
 End Sub
```

I have searched for a possible reason for this error but can not find any explanation.  I have noted in earlier versions of VB.net you had to enter code to save the child record, but the VB 2010 code does not seem to use the same syntax so I assumed the `UpdateAll` eliminated the need for the extra code

Comment: Just a side note as stated I can enter the data for the master or parent info and save the record without error.  I can then leave the record and come back and enter the detail or child portion of the record with out getting the error when I save,  The error only occurred when I try to complete and save both the master and detail.

Answer (score 0):

The error is effectively telling you either:

1) That the child record (tblComplaint) is being saved before the parent record (tblUseOfForce)

or

2) The child record's reference to the parent record (UOfID) is not being updated before the parent record is solved.

I suspect that number 2 is the most likely cause.

Hopefully this helps you ferret out the specific code that is causing this issue.